# Currency switching not happening for new products

Tags: magento

I have enable multi currency switcher on my magento store. Currency changes everywhere when i switch except for the new products slider. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

To fix this behaviour you need to disable caching for this particular block. It can be done by adding cache_lifetime=”1″ parameter to our shortcode.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" cache_lifetime="1"}}
```

I found it here - http://nwdthemes.com/2014/10/16/magento-new-products-block-change-currency/

Comment: It works, thanks. I noticed this only with 1.9.1.0 version but not with 1.9.0.1

Comment: Actually this bug was present in 1.7.x.x and 1.8.x.x

Answer (score 3):

Add a cache block, in  xml layout (cms.xml or page.xml) page where new product blongs.

```
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="newproducts" products_count="20" template="catalog/product/new.phtml">

<action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>0</s></action>  // add this line
```